# Is there any ndk media framework api to extract frames from a video file without using ffmpeg library and opencv

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, frame, media

I can extract frames from a video using MediaMetadataRetriever in java. But as per my project workflow I need this functionality to be performed in jni using ndk.

I don't want to use ffmpeg library and opencv.

Is there any api provided by ndk to extract a video frame by frame?

I also must perform colour adjustments on each frame. Please provide me information whether it is possible or not and also provide some sample code if it's possible.

I have been searching stackoverflow but my query not matched with any question that is previously asked.

Note: Not going to use ffmpeg or opencv.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use an external library like FFmpeg or openCV?
Gstreamer would be a good bet to make a pipeline to perform some frame colour adjustments.

If you want to use Native NDK you'll have to export the video to frames, edit those frames, and recompile to a new video, as it doesn't support direct video modification to the best of my knowledge: [NDK Media info](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#group___media_1ga96a484070c988c2092ea92d5b3c0c6de)

Comment: Because I'm going to replace previously implemented C++ code written already for desktop application with C++ code which is going to be written for mobile. If I used ffmpeg or opencv libraries it's going to be a different workflow. But ffmpeg and opencv are my last options. And I'm also thinking that it doesn't support direct video modification but more clarity needed for me before I go for other options.